# How to sort a list of childnode by the alphabetical order of child node and secondarily by the order of labeled edge in Java

Tags: java

This is a problem for the implementation of multiGraph class;
I implement my graph with:

```
List<String> parent; //which is the list of parent node
List<List<String>> child; //which is the 2d List containing list of child node of each parent node
List<List<String>> edge; //which is the 2d List containing relevant edge of that child node
```

I am currently trying to sort the list of child node by the alphabetical order which can be easily done by:

```
Collections.sort(List<T> list);
```

and I want to secondarily sort the list of child node by the alphabetical order of corresponding edges; what should I do for the second sort? or do I have some better ways to build my graph to make the sort much easier?

Comment: So, if *edge* derives from *child* I thin you can just build *edge* again on sorting *child* from the new sorted list of lists.

Comment: @Mario Santini Do you mean I rebuild the edge with sorted child then rebuild a new child with the new edge that needs to be sorted again?

Comment: As far as I understand from your question *child* and *edge* are connected as *edge* is the list of relevant edges of the *child* list. So I figured out that you build *edge* from *child*. I am wrong?

Comment: @MarioSantini true, for example, child.get(0) and edge.get(0) are the child list and the edge list of the first parent node; and the inside order is relevent.